# Предлог "в" или "во"?

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно: "в Львове" или "во Львове"? Каким правилом нужно руководствоваться в данном случае?

Comment: Это не местоимение, а предлог. Исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что именно тут надо объяснить? Форму предлога с гласной? Это фонетическое правило. "Во" используется вместо "в" пред скоплением согласных (почти всегда перед беглой гласной в первом слоге).

Answer (score 5):

Добавление гласного о к предлогу, состоящему из одного согласного звука или оканчивающемуся на согласный, наблюдается в ряде случаев:

1) перед односложным словом, начинающимся со стечения согласных, с беглым гласным в корне, например: во сне (ср.: в сновидениях), во рту (ср.: в ртутных испарениях), во льну (ср.: в льнотеребилках), ко мне (ср.: к мнимой величине);

2) часто после предлогов в и с, если с этих же согласных начинается последующее стечение согласных, например: во власти, во внушении, со слезами, со словами, со страху;

Розенталь Д. Э., Джанджакова Е. В., Кабанова Н. П. "Справочник по правописанию, 
произношению, литературному редактированию"

И еще по этой же теме:

Предлог во выступает перед формами слов, начинающимися сочетаниями «в, ф + согласный». Последовательно выступает перед формами слов *лев, лёд, лён, лоб, ложь, мох, ров, рожь, рот*, перед формой *мне* и формами слов *многие, многое, множество, множественный*, перед формой *что*. Также есть сочетания с *во* слов: *благо, весь, глава, двор, дворец, дворянство, зло, мгла, мнение, мрак, сколько, слава, сон, спасение, столько, тьма, христос, цвет, человек, чрево*.

Answer (score 3):

И еще по этой же теме.

Добавление гласного о к предлогу, состоящему из одного согласного звука или оканчивающемуся на согласный, наблюдается в ряде случаев:

1) перед односложным словом, начинающимся со стечения согласных, с беглым гласным в корне: во сне (ср.: в сновидениях), во рту (ср.: в ртутных испарениях), во льну (ср.: в льнотеребилках), ко мне (ср.: к мнимой величине);

2) часто после предлогов *в* и *с*, если с этих же согласных начинается последующее стечение согласных, например: во власти, во внушении, со слезами, со словами, со страху;

3) в отдельных фразеологических выражениях, например: во сто крат, изо всех сил, во главе войск;

4) в текстах, имеющих оттенок торжественности, например: «Во дни сомнений, во дни тягостных раздумий о судьбах моей родины...»;

5) в сочетаниях официального стиля, например: во избежание, во исполнение, во имя (перед начальным гласным в слове).

**Следующим описаниям не хватает обобщения и хотя бы элементарной теории.**

1) Обоснование для предлога ВО:

а) фонетическое: стечение согласных звуков с одинаковым (или смежным) местом образования;

б) традиционное и историческое;

в) стилистическое.

2) Определение области применения предлога *во*: только предлог *во*, допускаются оба варианта *в* и *во*, только предлог *в*.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: во Львове

Вопрос № 283417

Здравствуйте! Как правильно: "в Львове" или "во Львове"? И каким правилом это регламентируется? С одной стороны – привычно слышать "во". Но слово не начинается с в/ф, не является односложным с беглой гласной в корне, поэтому напрашивается вывод, что правильный вариант – это "в". Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Корректно: во Львове. Правила выбора предлога см. в «Письмовнике».http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/69-ko-dnu